# SOLR Block JOIN not returning data

Tags: solr

I have an issue with querying ***nested objects*** in SOLR 7.3.

I would like to get all **parent** objects using a BLOCK JOIN

```
curl http://localhost:8181/solr/prescriptions/query -d 'q={!parent which="contentType:parent"}*:*'
```

What do i need in my solrconfig.xml or managed-schema to get the above query to return data.

Note: It works if I create a test core `bin/solr create -c drugs` and push that data into it, i can query just fine with `curl http://localhost:8181/solr/perscriptions/query -d 'q={!parent which="contentType:parent"}*:*`, so it's my config skills are lacking here.

**Here's a little more detail**

solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
  <str name="wt">json</str>
  <str name="indent">true</str>
  <str name="mm">100%</str>
  <str name="defType">edismax</str>
  <str name="q.op">AND</str>
   <str name="df">allthengrams</str>
 </lst>
```

Example of my data

```
[
  {
    "id":"1111",
    "contentType":"parent",
    "npi":"1111111",
    "practiceType":"PSYCHIATRY",
    "_childDocuments_":[
    {
      "id":"1111111_10000",
      "parentProviderId":"1111111",
      "contentType":"prescription",
      "productName":"HYDROXYZINE PAM"
    },
    {
      "id":"1111111_10284",
      "parentProviderId":"1111111",
      "contentType":"prescription",
      "productName":"NALTREXONE HCL"
    }
  }
]
```

This returns no data

```
curl http://localhost:8181/solr/prescriptions/query -d 'q={!parent which="contentType:parent"}(id:1111)'
```

This returns data ( note I need to place the block join in the Filter Query).

```
curl http://localhost:8181/solr/prescriptions/query -d 'q=*&fq={!parent which="contentType:parent"}(id:1111)'
```

Comment: Initial guess - your first query doesn't specify an actual query. `q={!parent which="contentType:parent"}*:*` at least gives a query together with the localparam.

Comment: good spot, but unfortunately not the cause of my issue. Right now i'm comparing the ```solr/configsets/_default/conf/solrconfig.xml``` to my own solrconfig.xml. it must be a setting i'm missing

Comment: If I remove the ```typedef=edismax``` it works. so i guess that's the issue. But would love to hear how to make it work with edismax